# PhpStorm: Identifiers are automatically quoted, even variables

Tags: t-sql, intellij-idea, phpstorm

PhpStorm is adding errors into my code whenever I let the automatic code inspection run. I like using it when committing, because it fixes my indentation.

Here's my code with testing values before the commit:

```
/**
 * Calculates and selects the average score of a single user.
 * This will also have to calculate the score in different criteria.
 */

DECLARE @Max_Grade INTEGER
SET @Max_Grade = 6

DECLARE @User_ID INTEGER
SET @User_ID = 16

DECLARE @Basic_Weight INTEGER
SET @Basic_Weight = 10

DECLARE @Daily_Weight FLOAT
SET @Daily_Weight = 0.5

-- Create temporary utility table.
-- This table will contain each appraisal and its maximum score vs. total score of all
-- questions.
DECLARE @Score_Table TABLE
(
  [Appraisal_ID]  INTEGER,
  [Total_Score]   FLOAT,
  [Maximum_Score] FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Score_Table (
  [Appraisal_ID],
  [Total_Score],
  [Maximum_Score]
) (
  SELECT
      [Appraisal].[Appraisal_ID] AS [Appraisal_ID]
    , SUM(
          [Question].[Grade] *
          (
            @Basic_Weight +
            @Daily_Weight * DATEDIFF(DAY, [Plan].[From_Time], [Plan].[To_Time])
          )
      )
                                 AS [Total_Score]
    , SUM(
          @Max_Grade *
          (
            @Basic_Weight +
            @Daily_Weight * DATEDIFF(DAY, [Plan].[From_Time], [Plan].[To_Time])
          )
      )
                                 AS [Maximum_Score]
  FROM
    [Question], [Appraisal], [Plan]
  WHERE
    [Question].[Grade] IS NOT NULL AND
    [Question].[Grade] != 0 AND
    [Appraisal].[Appraisal_ID] = [Question].[Appraisal_ID] AND
    [Plan].[Plan_ID] = [Appraisal].[Plan_ID] AND
    [Appraisal].[User_ID_Candidate] = @User_ID AND
    [Appraisal].[Disabled] IS NULL AND

    -- DONE Criterium: Only count those appraisals that are completed
    [Appraisal].[Choice_Candidate] IS NOT NULL AND
    [Appraisal].[Choice_Candidate] <> 0 AND
    [Appraisal].[Choice_Owner] IS NOT NULL AND
    [Appraisal].[Choice_Owner] <> 0

  GROUP BY [Appraisal].[Appraisal_ID]
)

SELECT
  NULL,
  -- Calculate the end result by dividing the final results and multiplaying by maximum grade
  (
    SUM([Total_Score]) /
    SUM([Maximum_Score])
  ) * @Max_Grade
FROM @Score_Table

UNION

-- Select all grades as floats
SELECT
  [Appraisal_ID],

  -- Divide the actual weighted grade by the maximum weighted grade and multiply it by the maximum grade to get the
  -- average score of each
  -- appraisal.

  -- Total Score:
  [Total_Score] /
  -- Divided by Maximum Score:
  [Maximum_Score] * @Max_Grade
    AS [Average_Grade]

FROM @Score_Table
```

Committing and letting the automatic code scan run will change several lines, putting three variables all over the code into [brackets] - all occurrences except for their declarations.

```
/**
 * Calculates and selects the average score of a single user.
 * This will also have to calculate the score in different criteria.
 */

DECLARE @Max_Grade INTEGER
SET @Max_Grade = 6

DECLARE @User_ID INTEGER
SET @User_ID = 16

DECLARE @Basic_Weight INTEGER
SET @Basic_Weight = 10

DECLARE @Daily_Weight FLOAT
SET @Daily_Weight = 0.5

-- Create temporary utility table.
-- This table will contain each appraisal and its maximum score vs. total score of all
-- questions.
DECLARE [@Score_Table] TABLE
(
  [Appraisal_ID]  INTEGER,
  [Total_Score]   FLOAT,
  [Maximum_Score] FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO [@Score_Table] (
  [Appraisal_ID],
  [Total_Score],
  [Maximum_Score]
) (
  SELECT
      [Appraisal].[Appraisal_ID] AS [Appraisal_ID]
    , SUM(
          [Question].[Grade] *
          (
            [@Basic_Weight] +
            [@Daily_Weight] * DATEDIFF(DAY, [Plan].[From_Time], [Plan].[To_Time])
          )
      )
                                 AS [Total_Score]
    , SUM(
          [@Max_Grade] *
          (
            [@Basic_Weight] +
            [@Daily_Weight] * DATEDIFF(DAY, [Plan].[From_Time], [Plan].[To_Time])
          )
      )
                                 AS [Maximum_Score]
  FROM
    [Question], [Appraisal], [Plan]
  WHERE
    [Question].[Grade] IS NOT NULL AND
    [Question].[Grade] != 0 AND
    [Appraisal].[Appraisal_ID] = [Question].[Appraisal_ID] AND
    [Plan].[Plan_ID] = [Appraisal].[Plan_ID] AND
    [Appraisal].[User_ID_Candidate] = @User_ID AND
    [Appraisal].[Disabled] IS NULL AND

    -- DONE Criterium: Only count those appraisals that are completed
    [Appraisal].[Choice_Candidate] IS NOT NULL AND
    [Appraisal].[Choice_Candidate] <> 0 AND
    [Appraisal].[Choice_Owner] IS NOT NULL AND
    [Appraisal].[Choice_Owner] <> 0

  GROUP BY [Appraisal].[Appraisal_ID]
)

SELECT
  NULL,
  -- Calculate the end result by dividing the final results and multiplaying by maximum grade
  (
    SUM([Total_Score]) /
    SUM([Maximum_Score])
  ) * @Max_Grade
FROM @Score_Table

UNION

-- Select all grades as floats
SELECT
  [Appraisal_ID],

  -- Divide the actual weighted grade by the maximum weighted grade and multiply it by the maximum grade to get the
  -- average score of each
  -- appraisal.

  -- Total Score:
  [Total_Score] /
  -- Divided by Maximum Score:
  [Maximum_Score] * @Max_Grade
    AS [Average_Grade]

FROM @Score_Table
```

All four variables except for `@User_ID` are automatically quoted. Unfortunately, the script breaks in lines 21, 77 and 95 because of the inconsistent quoting of variables. I don't think you could even declare them if you quote them.

The feature is disabled in both the IDE config and the project default config:

[image: config project]

[image: config IDE]

I've tried code inspection with and without this option.

Version/About:

[image]

Could anyone point me into the right direction? I could exclude the file from the automatic code inspection, but before I start excluding several files because of this issue, I'd like to hear alternative solutions.

Comment: **Inspections are just for reporting -- they will not change your code in any way.** Some inspections may provide "Intentions" (quick fixes) .. but you still have to invoke them manually. So .. this most likely be your Code Style settings (IDE or you may be running Code Formatting before committing) -- please check there.

Comment: Thanks, will do!

Comment: I've posted an answer. Thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

As @LazyOne said, the Code Style must be edited. There's an option to change Identifier Quotation. Mine was on.

[image]